# Date Diff By Ignoring Leap Days

Tags: c#, logic

Please share some logic to find date difference between two dates which would ignore leap days, c# Subtract method includes the leap days.
E.g. for startDat= 26-02-2016 and endDate= 03-03-2016
I want answer to be 5 and not 6. Similarly for any other years.

Thanks!

Comment: We don't write code for you.  Show us what you've tried, and tell us what isn't working, then we might be able to help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: You can probably add some conditional logic to check if it is a leap year and then go from there.  As a starter, try doing something like startDat.IsLeapYear()

Comment: As I mentioned in my queston, what I tried is endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays :)

Comment: If you use `DateTime` it will take leap days into account, why wouldn't you want it to do that?

Comment: I know by using long Brut force alog's I can achieve this. But I want it to be done elegantly. e..g at one place match trick is used like "int days = (end.year-start.year)*365 + end.dayOfYear - start.dayOfYear;" but this solution breaks with  the example given in my question.

Comment: This does seem like an odd request. If you implement what you're asking then your result will be wrong.

Comment: In the context of my application requirement it's a perfectly valid request, please suggest some elegant way to achieve this :)

Comment: Check if it is a leap year using the above method mentioned, then check if the date of 2/29 is between your two dates and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is the following:

```
public static int DayDiff(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    DateTime min, max;
    if(d1 < d2)
    {
        min = d1; max = d2;
    }
    else
    {
        min = d2; max = d1;
    }

    int nbOfDays = 0;
    while(max.Date != min.Date)
    {
        min = min.AddDays(1);
        if (min.Month != 2 || min.Day != 29) // Skip leap day
            nbOfDays++;
    }
    return nbOfDays;
}
```

Comment: This logic fails for following values var d1 = new DateTime(2016, 06, 30);
                var d2 = new DateTime(2021, 06, 30);

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most complicated way of doing this but it survived my test cases and seems to get the job done.

1. Calculate the difference in total years `Years`.
2. Compute the `Days` of the remaining interval.
3. Check it for a leap day. If there is one, compute `--Days`.
4. Return `Days + Years * 365`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines the ABSOLUTE difference of FULL years between two dates.
/// Leap days are ignored; the 29th of February is treated as if it was the 28th
/// (conforming with Aventurian calendars).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Early">The earlier date</param>
/// <param name="Late">The later date</param>
/// <returns>Difference in full years (absolute value >= 0)</returns>
public static int AbsDeltaInYears(DateTime Early, DateTime Late)
{
    if (Early > Late) throw new ArgumentException("'Late' must be greater or equal to 'Early'");

    // Aventurian calendars do not have leap years: check for Feb, 29th
    const int Feb = 2;
    const int LeapDay = 29;
    if (Early.Day == LeapDay && Early.Month == Feb) Early = Early.AddDays(-1);
    if (Late.Day == LeapDay && Late.Month == Feb) Late = Late.AddDays(-1);

    int Delta = Late.Year - Early.Year;

    // correction if the one year is not a full year
    if (Late.Month < Early.Month || (Late.Month == Early.Month && Late.Day < Early.Day))
        Delta--;

    return Delta;
}


/// <summary>
/// Calculate the difference in days (ignoring leap days which the Aventurian calendar does not have).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="time"></param>
/// <param name="reference"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int DeltaInDays(DateTime time, DateTime reference)
{
    // Needed to determine leap years
    GregorianCalendar EarthCalendar = new();

    DateTime Early = time <= reference ? time : reference;
    DateTime Late = time > reference ? time : reference;
    int Years = AbsDeltaInYears(Early, Late);

    // skip leap days by using whole years
    int Days = Years * DaysInYear;
    // add remaining interval
    DateTime EarlyPlusYears = Early.AddYears(Years);
    Days += (Late - EarlyPlusYears).Days;
    // One leap day may be left, remove if necessary
    if (EarthCalendar.IsLeapYear(EarlyPlusYears.Year) && EarlyPlusYears.DayOfYear < 31 + 29)
        Days--;
    else
    {
        if (EarthCalendar.IsLeapYear(Late.Year) && Late.DayOfYear > 31 + 28)
            Days--;
    }
    return Days;
}
```